# Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bustracker.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.content.BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a MainActivity class which contains BroadcastReceiver to catch system broadcast(Internet connection and wifi scan result). I am facing a problem the internet connection broadcast is being  received and displayed  as Toast but the wifi scan results condition "if (intent.getAction().equals(android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION))" is not being reached from the program. Does anyone have an idea where the problem is? Is something wrong with the defintion of the receiver in the manifest?

```
04-08 23:16:34.319: E/AndroidRuntime(13291): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 23:16:34.319: E/AndroidRuntime(13291): Process: com.bustracker, PID: 13291
04-08 23:16:34.319: E/AndroidRuntime(13291): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.bustracker.MainActivity: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bustracker.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.content.BroadcastReceiver
04-08 23:16:34.319: E/AndroidRuntime(13291):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2518)
04-08 23:16:34.319: E/AndroidRuntime(13291):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:161)
04-08 23:16:34.319: E/AndroidRuntime(13291):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
04-08 23:16:34.319: E/AndroidRuntime(13291):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-08 23:16:34.319: E/AndroidRuntime(13291):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
04-08 23:16:34.319: E/AndroidRuntime(13291):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
04-08 23:16:34.319: E/AndroidRuntime(13291):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 23:16:34.319: E/AndroidRuntime(13291):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-08 23:16:34.319: E/AndroidRuntime(13291):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
04-08 23:16:34.319: E/AndroidRuntime(13291):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
04-08 23:16:34.319: E/AndroidRuntime(13291):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 23:16:34.319: E/AndroidRuntime(13291): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bustracker.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.content.BroadcastReceiver
04-08 23:16:34.319: E/AndroidRuntime(13291):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2513)
04-08 23:16:34.319: E/AndroidRuntime(13291):    ... 10 more
```

Activity code:

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(
                android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(
                android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {

        }
    }
};

protected void onResume() {
    IntentFilter conn = new IntentFilter();
    conn.addAction(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(receiver, conn);

    IntentFilter wifi = new IntentFilter();
    wifi.addAction(android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(receiver, wifi);

    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `<receiver>` element pointing to `MainActivity`.

First, that's wrong, as `MainActivity` is not a `BroadcastReceiver`. That is what your exception is telling you.

Second, you are *also* registering for these broadcasts via `registerReceiver()`. It is **very** unlikely that you want to be **both** registering in the manifest **and** registering via `registerReceiver()`.

I would start by commenting out the `<receiver>` element (since it is clearly wrong) and proceeding from there.

Comment: please check my updated code. Is still not working. I registered both and I deleted the receiver in the mainfest. CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcat works but SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION still does not work.

Comment: @MrAsker: You can only call `registerReceiver()` once per `BroadcastReceiver` instance. Either create an `IntentFilter` for both actions, or use two separate `BroadcastReceiver` instances.